# Adding more claims to JWT obtained externally (ASP NET)

Tags: asp.net, authentication, jwt, authorization, claims-based-identity

So at work I was given the task of designing a database API, now security assessment has stated that the system must use Authentication and Authorization.

On top of that Authentication Happens through their NetScalar that forces the user to login with company credentials and in turn gives the user a token. This token will then be sent to my API in the header of each request.

Now here comes the issue. The token only contains a username, I however want to do a

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

Check on my controllers. Now as the user has already been authenticated with his password and username I know that he has is a valid user however I would like to assign a role to him.

Now I'm open for suggestions on how to do this but the simplest way of fixing this that I could think of was to at each request query my DB for the users role and add it to the token claims.

However I don't know how to do this and also I have no idea if this is a good solution.
I would appreciate any help with adding the claims (in code) or other solution (also code would be much appreciated).

Thank you!

Comment: JWTs are signed, any change of the payload will invalidate the signature. You can only add claims before the token is signed.

Comment: Ok then the token has a value called group. I want to use this value with my authorize tags.  Like [Authorize(group = employed)], any idea how ?

Comment: Also u might have misunderstood im not sending this token to the user, this is the token i receive from user that they got via 3rd party.

Comment: I understood that you got the token from a 3rd party and told you that,  because of the signature, "Adding more claims to JWT obtained externally" is not an option (unless you can influence the way the token gets created)

Comment: ok I see ill have to find another way then. Thank you.